# In my C# XAML Windows 8.1 app, how can I iterate over my ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, windows-8.1

I'm new to Windows 8.1 development, XAML, and C#, so if this question is rudimentary, please forgive me.

I've got a `<Page>` in my app that contains a `<ListView>`, like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="ListView_Statistical">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Width="100"  Margin="10,20">
                    <Run Text="X/Y " />
                    <!--<Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ThisPage}, Path=i}" />-->
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding xVal}" PlaceholderText="X" InputScope="Number" FontSize="28" Width="100" Margin="0,10,10,10" />
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding yVal}" PlaceholderText="Y" InputScope="Number" FontSize="28" Width="100" Margin="0,10,10,10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the Code Behind, I set up its DataContext like so:

```
ListView_Statistical.DataContext = this.statisticalPoints;
```

`this.statisticalPoints` is defined as such:

```
public ObservableCollection<StatisticalPoint> statisticalPoints
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<StatisticalPoint>)GetValue(statisticalPointsProperty); }
    set { 
        SetValue(statisticalPointsProperty, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("statisticalPoints");
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for statisticalPoints.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty statisticalPointsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("statisticalPoints", typeof(ObservableCollection<StatisticalPoint>), typeof(EnterCalc), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

I'm not sure if making this a DependencyProperty is necessary, or if making it follow INotifyPropertyChanged is necessary, but they don't seem to *hurt*.

Anyway, so in my constructor, I add a bunch of stuff to my statisticalPoints:

```
this.statisticalPoints = new ObservableCollection<StatisticalPoint>();
this.statisticalPoints.Add(new StatisticalPoint() { xVal = 1.0, yVal = 2.0 });
this.statisticalPoints.Add(new StatisticalPoint() { xVal = 33.0, yVal = 44.0 });
this.statisticalPoints.Add(new StatisticalPoint() { xVal = 555.0, yVal = 666.0 });
this.statisticalPoints.Add(new StatisticalPoint() { xVal = 0.7, yVal = 0.8 });
```

And when I load up the page, I do indeed see five rows in my `ListView`, populated as defined in my initialization of `this.statisticalPoints`.

The part I'm having trouble with is this:

I change the first value in the first `<TextBox>` in the `ListView`, then hit my save button... but ListView.Items doesn't have my change reflected, and I can't figure out how to look at the `<TextBox>` itself.

What I really want to do is have this bunch of statistical points modifiable by my user and be able to save their changes.  To do that, I feel like I need to read the value in the `<TextBox>`es, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Alternatively, if the 'right way' to do this is to keep the data in `this.statisticalPoints` up-to-date when changes are made in the `<TextBox>`es, then I thought that a `TwoWay` binding Mode would do it, but neither `ListView.Items` nor `this.statisticalPoints` is changed when I make changes in the `<TextBox>`.

I *do not* have event handlers set up in those `<TextBox>` elements, as you can see, but do I need them, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your *initial* problem, make the binding for each text box `Mode="TwoWay"`. For reasons beyond my comprehension, the mode is default `OneWay` on pretty much everything in Windows Store Apps.

Making the `ItemsSource` binding two way does next to nothing, as the UI isn't changing the collection *itself* (by changing, I mean completely replacing). To iterate over your collection, just iterate over `this.statisticalPoints` and it will have the current data.

Now, you have a ton of other misconceptions so to try and run through them:

- You never showed your save button, but the bindings either update your source or they don't. A save button is usually used to persist changes from the view model to the model.
- Speaking of view models, you don't appear to have one. You shouldn't be directly setting the data context of controls, and certainly shouldn't have so much in code-behind. Create a proper view model object for your page, and bind `ItemsSource` to a public property of that view model.
- NotifyPropertyChanged on a collection *usually* is unnecessary unless you are replacing the collection in code.
- Having it won't hurt though, except, the setter of the backing property of a DependencyProperty (DP) is *never* called by the framework, so putting it there is just *weird*
- And you don't really need a DP at all. DPs are there so a parent control can bind data to your special user control. Until you are using user controls, and really understand how DPs work, you shouldn't need to use them.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer!  I really have about 0% understanding of DependencyProperties (even a basic definition), as the documentation uses terminology that is never explained anywhere that I can find, and doesn't contain any examples that elucidate things.  Any idea where there's a 'DependencyProperties laid out step by step for folks who want to understand them' type of source?  I'd be deeply grateful for that.  =)

Comment: In order to reduce complications and variables, I'm using this page as its own ViewModel for this super-simple example.  Since I don't really know what does what, just making everything a DependencyProperty and making everything follow INotifyPropertyChanged was my best guess at trying to get [literally anything] to work.  Then, once I get something to work, I can pare out the pieces one by one to figure out what's necessary.  I fully expect that half or more of the things in here are unnecessary.

Comment: Also, just to clarify a bit more, am I correct in saying that if I make the Binding Mode TwoWay, then changes in the TextBoxes will immediately and automatically change the data in the bound StatisticalPoint?  So I don't need to iterate over the TextBox UI elements, because the data will already be in my backing data structure?  That would be my ideal, because I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the TextBoxes (I see no properties or methods on ListView that lets you get access to its children in the UI).

Comment: Oh, also, my SaveButton_Click method does a ton of stuff from a static implementation that I'm moving away from (5 Rows in a Grid, each with two TextBoxes, one for X and one for Y), takes the values in the TextBoxes and serializes them to JSON and saves them to a text file.  So I left that part out intentionally, as it's not anywhere close to where it needs to be.  In fact, the reason I need to know how to get the data back out of my UI with the ListView implementation is so I *can* swap out the SaveButton_Click implementation.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @KyleHumfeld Not sure as far as understandability, but the WPF page for them is good: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (note that DPs work the same in WinRT and WPF). Having a seperate view model, in addition to being better design, would have made you quickly realize that DPs weren't right, because you would have had to make your VM a `DependencyObject`. Its not that hard to make a class, doing it right is worth it!

Comment: @KyleHumfeld To your third comment, yes your understanding is correct. It will actually update the source property based on the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding, which is usually set to `LostFocus`. As to your save button, just have it iterate over the bound collection. It shouldn't be touching the UI at all. Consider joining us in the WPF chat room, or I can set up a private room, if you want to chat about this.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It's less thick than the page I found before (WinRT-specific, I think), so I might have some prayer of understanding that it's trying to say.  However, I don't follow one thing you wrote, namely 'because you would have had to make your VM a DependencyObject'.  Why would I have to do that, would that be right or wrong, and how would I know that that's right or wrong?

Comment: (at)BradleyDotNET, I never even knew SO had chat rooms, but I see that little link snuggled in the footer now.  I'll probably get back to my C# work tomorrow, in which case maybe I'll see you there.  Thanks for the invite!

Comment: @KyleHumfeld You would have to do that because you can't have a DP unless you derive from DependencyObject (which the UI controls already do). I would think that behavior would be odd enough that you would second guess your decision to use a DP :) IIRC its in a UI namespace as well. Here's the WPF room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf